# d3 - understanding the documentation for d3.svg.line

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I must be missing something incredibly simple here. I'm wanting to use [d3.svg.line](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/SVG-Shapes#svg_line) to draw a line between two points. The documentation is below:

> svg:line x1="0" y1="0" x2="0" y2="0"
>   The line element defines a line segment that starts at one point and ends at another. The first point is specified using the x1 and y1 attributes, while the second point is specified using the x2 and y2 attributes. The line element is a popular choice for drawing rules, reference lines, axes and tick marks.

What I don't understand (given the lack of inline examples in the documentation) is how x1, y1, x2 and y2 fit in to the picture. All the examples using `d3.svg.line` that I saw don't use them at all, and instead use a data array and a function to draw a line between **multiple points** (eg. http://jsfiddle.net/5e2HD/1/ and https://www.dashingd3js.com/svg-paths-and-d3js).

Whenever I try to use x1, x2, y1, and y2 in any way (eg. setting them as attributes on my line, calling them as functions, passing them as parameters, etc) I get errors. How would you use `d3.svg.line` to simply create a straight line between two points, as the documentation seems to indicate it's meant for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", 500)
    .attr("height", 500);
svg.append("line").attr("x1",200).attr("y1",200).attr("x2",400).attr("y2",400).attr("style","stroke:rgb(255,0,0);stroke-width:2")`

Comment: This doesn't use the d3.svg.line path that I linked to above - I'm specifically asking about how to create a 'line' by using a path build by d3.svg.line().

Comment: d3.svg.line() is a path generator function, which you can use to generate (x,y) coordinates out of your data and then draw lines using path. The code above was to use line object directly.

Comment: I understand that. What I don't understand is why the documentation for d3.svg.line mentions x1, y1, x2 and y2 - how do they fit in to the picture, when you're using d3.svg.line? I understand how they fit in if you're adding a plain old line using append('line'), but I don't understand why they're mentioned in the documentation for d3.svg.line.

Comment: Sorry, I am not sure whether i am looking at a different section, but the link in the question points to svg elements section and the line in that has an hyperlink to svg line element. I dont think that this is anything specific to d3 but a general SVG element. Whereas d3.svg.line in ([link](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/SVG-Shapes#path-data-generators))is helper function from d3 which helps to generate points and draw a line using path element.

Comment: Ah, right you are. So the d3 doco contains a section on generic SVG shapes, not specific to d3, and then below that has a section defining d3 path generators - and d3.svg.line (the path generator within d3) isn't really related to svg.line (the plain line shape, part of the SVG spec, not specific to d3) in any way. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Hope this helps. Check the line generator function and the last part where I am adding the path

```js
// The data for our line
var lineData = [{
    x: 50,
    y: 50
}, {
    x: 50,
    y: 100
}, {
    x: 100,
    y: 150
}, {
    x: 150,
    y: 175
}, {
    x: 225,
    y: 175
}];

// Set the size of our graph
var w = 500;
var h = 500;
var padding = 10;


// Line generator function
var line = d3.svg.line()
    .x(function (d) {
    return d.x;
})
    .y(function (d) {
    return d.y;
})


// SVG container
var svg = d3.select('#line')
    .append('svg')
    .attr({
    width: w,
    height: h
});

// Add the path
var path = svg.append('path')
    .attr("d", line(lineData))
    .attr("stroke", "blue")
    .attr("stroke-width", 2)
    .attr("fill", "none");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<div id="line"></div>
```